# Materialize css behaving different online and offline

Tags: html, css, material-design, materialize

I am having a problem as explained in the title; CSS is behaving differently online and offline.

Offline, I changed few CSS rules to have the navigation I wanted.
[image: Offline look]
Online, it reverts back to its default look.
[image: Online look]

HTML is drafted like this:

```
<div class="navbar-fixed">
    <nav id="jeboteled">
        <div id="boja" class="nav-wrapper">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col s12 center-align logoSlikaNav">
                        <a href="#" data-target="mobile-demo" class="sidenav-trigger">
                                <i class="material-icons">menu</i>
                           </a>
                    <a href="index.html" class="hide-on-med-and-down">
                        <img style="width: 100px; height:50px;" src="img/opcanamjena/holiday_header.png">
                    </a> 
                </div>
                <a href="#">

                <div class="col s2 center-align hide-on-med-and-down linkDiv tooltipped" data-position="bottom" data-tooltip="Accomodation">
                                <i class="fas fa-bed"></i>
                </div>
            </a>

                <a href="Adventure.html">

                <div class="col s2 center-align hide-on-med-and-down linkDiv tooltipped" data-position="bottom" data-tooltip="Adventure">
                                <i class="fas fa-motorcycle"></i>
                </div>
            </a>

                <a href="explore.html">

                <div class="col s2 center-align hide-on-med-and-down linkDiv tooltipped" data-position="bottom" data-tooltip="Explore">
                                <i class="fas fa-compass"></i>
                </div>
            </a>

                <a href="Gastronomy.html">
                <div class="col s2 center-align hide-on-med-and-down linkDiv tooltipped" data-position="bottom" data-tooltip="Gastronomy">
                                <i class="fas fa-utensils"></i>
                </div>
            </a>

                <div class="col s2 center-align hide-on-med-and-down linkDiv tooltipped" onclick="overlaycontactopen()" data-position="bottom" data-tooltip="Contact">
                    <i class="fas fa-info-circle"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="col s2 center-align hide-on-med-and-down linkDiv tooltipped modal-trigger" href="#jezik" data-position="bottom" data-tooltip="Language">
                    <i class="fas fa-language"></i>
                </div>
            </div>           
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
```

this is the only CSS rule that is changed. Everything else is as in materialize css file.

```
#boja {
background-color: #18185e !important;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 993px) {
#jeboteled {
    height: 150px;
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 993px) {
.logoSlikaNav {
    transform: translateY(10px);
     } 
}

.linkDiv {
cursor: pointer;
}

.linkDiv:hover {
background-color: #61b9f6;
}
```

Here is the test site where it is posted.

https://jedantest.000webhostapp.com/

Comment: 1) Try clearing cache in your browser. 2) Check your CSS file in chrome developer tools, does it match the one you're running in local?

Comment: wow... it solved the problem... I can't believe i didn't see the simplest solution. Thank you

Comment: No problem. Clearing cache will become second nature in web development, you'll get used to it :-)

Answer (score 0):

As stated by alexr101 in comments, clearing cache did the trick!